# Can I mount a computer's hard drive to a raspberry pi without taking it out (Using GPIO, USB)?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, usb, windows

I have a project in which I have to access Windows computer's hard disk on a raspberry pi running Linux. Is there any way that I can mount the hard disk to the raspberry pi without taking it out of the machine itself?

I mean I know both devices are master devices so IDK I just need to make it work somehow.

Comment: I think you probably want to investigate Samba: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)

Comment: For a real `mount` you can use `NFS` (Network File System). You could windows pc boot with a Linux Live System and export the disk mount to your network and then mount it on the raspi.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_Data_Platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to access the full, raw disk or just some data (files) on the disk?

If you need to mount the raw disk, I'm afraid your going to need to take the disk out and use a USB external HDD adapter. (search your favourite on-line supplier)

If you just need file/directory data, and if the other computer is up and operational, you can mount the remote disk using the cifs-utils software.

If not installed: "sudo apt-get install cifs-utils"

Create or identify a mount point: "sudo mkdir /mnt/your-mount-point"

Then to mount: "mount.cifs //[IP_Addr]/[FolderName]  /mnt/[your-mount-point] -o username=[WindowsUser]"

The gory details are in "man mount.cifs"

Or:

You can use the 'smbclient' package, an ftp-like client to access SMB/CIFS files on networked Widows systems

If not installed: "sudo apt-get install smbclient".  Then you can use "man smbclient" to get the detailed details.